# Submultiplicative Matrix Norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Given $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, $F$ an $n\times n$ matrix with $\|F\|_{M} < 1$ for some submultiplicative norm $\|.\|_M$, by which formula is $(I+F)^{-1}$ calculable? And is it necessary at all that $\|F\|_{M} < 1$?

Comment: If $\|F\| <1$, then you can check the series $\sum_{n \ge 0} (-F)^n$ converges to $(I+F)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\|F\|<1$ is certainly *not* a necessary condition, because when $F=kI$, the matrix $I+F$ is invertible for every $k\not=-1$. Nonetheless, $\|F\|<1$ provides a very useful criterion for the existence of $(I+F)^{-1}$ and I am not aware of any other sufficient condition on the invertibility of $I+F$ based on matrix norm. It's plausible that alternative sufficient condition exist. In fact, using the sufficient condition $\|F\|<1$, we may create a similar one:

> $I+F$ is invertible ***if*** $F$ is invertible and $\|F^{-1}\|<1$.

(Proof: $\|F^{-1}\|<1$ implies that $(I + F^{-1})^{-1}$ exists. Hence $(I+F)^{-1}=F^{-1} (I + F^{-1})^{-1}$.) However, it's hard to imagine that there is one as simple as $\|F\|<1$. If there is such a condition, we should have all seen it in many textbooks.

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I understand it correctly so far, that the inverse exists can be shown with the alternating series: $(I-(-F))^{-1} = I + R + R^2 + ...+ = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-F)^k$ and although here the norm of F has to be < 1, this approach itself is only a **sufficient** condition, right? Then I still have two questions: Why is actually $(I-(-F))^{-1} = I + R + R^2 + ...+$ and why is I + kI invertible except the diagonal elements are 2 (since k=1)?

Comment: @TestGuest $k\neq1$ is a typo. It should read $k\neq-1$. Yes, $\|F\|<1$ is a sufficient condition, not a necessary one. When $\|X\|<1$, the partial sums $S_n=I+X+X^2+\ldots+X^n$ form a Cauchy sequence: for any $\epsilon>0$, whenever $m\ge n\ge\sqrt[n+1]{(1-\|X\|)\epsilon}$, we have $\|S_m-S_n\|<\|X\|^{n+1}+\|X\|^{n+2}+\ldots+\|X\|^m\le \|X\|^{n+1}/(1-\|X\|)< \epsilon$. Therefore the infinite series $S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty X^n$ converges. But what does it converge to? As $(I-X)S_n=I-X^{n+1}$, the RHS converges to $I$ because $\|X\|^{n+1}$ converges to $0$. So, $(I-X)S=I$, or $S=(I-X)^{-1}$.